# what is the best software to decompile a java class file?

Tags: java, decompiler

How do you batch decompile many class files?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76314/open-java-class-files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[JD-Gui](http://java-decompiler.github.io/) makes your life easy, it also has an eclipse plugin

edit: updated the latest url for the tool

Answer (score 9):

I've used [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad) but I'm not sure if it supports the more recent changes (Update: it does not support language features introduced in java 1.5). Otherwise you might be able to write a small java app to do batch decompiling using the core of [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/).

Comment: I also recommend JAD. I have been using it for long, around 2 years!

Comment: and i found the latest version of JAD not support some java features.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include that. That leaves JD as the best option, you will have to do some programming to create a batch script unless the GUI accidentally fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jode](http://jode.sourceforge.net/). You can disassemble .class files or complete .jars in one go. Although it claims to be up to date to an early version of Java (1.3), I've had few problems with later Java versions.

Answer (score 0):

I just published a stand-alone Java Decompiler GUI (based on Jad) which you can get from Util [Java Decompiler (JAD based) v1.0](http://diniscruz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/util-java-decompiler-jad-based-v10exe.html)

This is a Windows based .NET 4.0 application, which supports the drag n'drop of *.jar files.

The code that creates that tool is a simple C# script (which you can see here: https://github.com/o2platform/O2.Platform.Scripts/tree/master/3rdParty/JAD ), so it would be easy to extend it to allow for the batch decompilation that you want to do.

It might be good to add support to the other Java decompilers, since JAD sometimes is not able to decompile some files.