# class file to java file conversion

Tags: java, decompiling

How to get java file i.e source code from class file i.e from compiled file?

Comment: Check this link : http://java.decompiler.free.fr/ Another one : http://www.varaneckas.com/jad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [javap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) for getting the source back from bytecode.

There are plenty of tools and plugin that help you to disassemble and you can find some discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383022/what-is-the-best-software-to-decompile-a-java-class-file).

Answer (score 5):

Check out [this](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) Java Decompiler.

Also see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) Wikipedia page to know more about decompilation.

*It should be noted that the code you get on decompilation of bytecode isn't very readable.*

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a disassembler.

[Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) is a good choice.

Also Java Decompiler has a plug-in for Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javap command to get the overall structure of the file.

On the side note: Best way to disable anyone from getting the source from your compiled code is to use obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cannot do anything like reverse conversion.

What you can do is modify the bytecode at runtime. That's allowed in Java...

Check for `java.lang.instrumentation` package. That will help you to achieve your goal to some extent...

Answer (score 0):

I just published a stand-alone Java Decompiler GUI (based on Jad) which you can get from Util [Java Decompiler (JAD based) v1.0](http://diniscruz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/util-java-decompiler-jad-based-v10exe.html)

This is a Windows based .NET 4.0 application, which supports the drag n'drop of *.jar files.