# check content in .class files

Tags: java, class, file, bytecode

Suppose one learned that certain developer hardcoded a bunch of usernames and passwords into application, which made it into Production. Oh-oh ..!

You know both username and password - is there a way to scan the bytecode and identify whether in fact username, password was hardcoded?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A simple way to see what String literals are used in a ".class" file is to use the [`javap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) utility in your JDK installation to dump the file using the "-v" option.  Then `grep` for text that looks like `<String "...">` where `...` is the String you are looking for.

**UPDATE**

The latest documentation for `javap` is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html), but the old version looks nicer IMO.

Answer (score 7):

You can use java decompilers to decompile your class (and to check whether the class contains hardcoded username/passwords)
Have a look at:

- [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui)
- [JAD](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/JAD.shtml)

Answer (score 7):

Have you looked into [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui)? You can see there if that has been hardcoded into any of the class files.

Answer (score 5):

May be helpful for others in future. (From [How can I open Java .class files in a human-readable way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76314/how-can-i-open-java-class-files-in-a-human-readable-way) )

```
Usage: javap <options> <classes>...

where options include:
   -c                        Disassemble the code
   -classpath <pathlist>     Specify where to find user class files
   -extdirs <dirs>           Override location of installed extensions
   -help                     Print this usage message
   -J<flag>                  Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
   -l                        Print line number and local variable tables
   -public                   Show only public classes and members
   -protected                Show protected/public classes and members
   -package                  Show package/protected/public classes
                             and members (default)
   -private                  Show all classes and members
   -s                        Print internal type signatures
   -bootclasspath <pathlist> Override location of class files loaded
                             by the bootstrap class loader
   -verbose                  Print stack size, number of locals and args for methods
                             If verifying, print reasons for failure
```