# I use notepad++ to look javac's soure code,but when I open ,I just see something I can't understand

Tags: java, notepad++, notepad

[image]

[image]

I open this file with ANSIC code,so how can I solve this problem?

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76314/how-can-i-open-java-class-files-in-a-human-readable-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not Java source code.

.class files are compiled Java binary class files.

.java files have the source code.

If you are looking for the source code of the Java compiler (javac), you can [get that from OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/). But it's a big and complex project.

Comment: so your mean is that I should open with a .java file notepad++,and can't open with a .class file in notepad++？

Comment: Yes, you cannot read a .class file. It is a binary file (like an .exe or a .jpg).

Comment: Is there any way I can transate .class to .java ?

Comment: a) yes, checked the linked question provided in comments.  b) in this case: why? the source code is freely available at OpenJDK

Comment: yeah, I open this linked in my browser ,but I can't find a way to serch for javac.exe's .java file.Is there any way?

Comment: That's a couple of hundred source files at least... Here is the `public static void main` for javac: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/file/1ff9d5118aae/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/Main.java

Comment: And here are some notes for newcomers to javac source: http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/doc/hhgtjavac/index.html

Comment: great, I wonder how can you find it in hundreds of codes?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? You can download the source and browse it in an IDE more conveniently than in a text editor.

Comment: well,I just mean how can you find javac 's .java file so quickly in the linked you gaven to me before ?

Comment: there is "browse" in the side menu. That shows the tree of files (similar to the one in your screenshot).

Comment: but there is so much,I can't figure out which is javac without the linked you just give me before,sad